# How to deserialize a JSON array with nested arrays of objects

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON string as follows and want to deserialize it:

```
[[{"campaignId":201410018,"programCode":"54321"}],[{"campaignId":201410018,"programCode":"54321"}]]
```

I have created some classes as follows:

```
public class Rootclass
{
    public List<JSONResponse> rootClass { get; set; }
}

public class JSONResponse
{
    public int campaignId { get; set; }
    public string programCode { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling this JSON.NET method to deserialize the JSON:

```
List<Rootclass> myDeserializedObjList = (List<Rootclass>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(List<Rootclass>));
```

But I am getting the error below:

```
Cannot deserialize JSON array (i.e. [1,2,3]) into type 'JSON_Test.Rootclass'.
The deserialized type must be an array or implement a collection interface like IEnumerable, ICollection or IList.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON represents a `List<List<JSONResponse>>`, not a `List<RootClass>`.  Try it like this:

```
List<List<JSONResponse>> myDeserializedObjList = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<JSONResponse>>>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/geRLdb

Comment: How can a deserialize below JSON string.
string json = @"[[{""campaignId"":201410018,""programCode"":""54321""},{""reason"":201410018,""about"":""54321""}],[{""campaignId"":201410019,""programCode"":""54322""},{""reason"":201410018,""about"":""54321""}]]";

Comment: There are several possible solutions. The quick-and-dirty way is simply to add the `reason` and `about` properties to your `JSONResponse` object.   See [fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Stz6o2).  If you want separate classes for the objects containing `campaignId` versus `reason`, then you will need to use a [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).  A third possibility is to deserialize to a `dynamic` or a `JToken` instead of using strongly-typed classes.