# Deserialize Json string to Dictionary<int,List<T>>

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization

How the best way to deserialize the follow json string, without dynamic type, in C#?

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var table = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<int,List<T>>>(json);

[[{
   "value": "1.19",
   "datevalue": "2016-03-19 19:33:13",  
   "winflag": "1",
   "idmercado": "1"
   },
   {
   "value": "1.22",
   "datevalue": "2016-03-19 19:33:13",
   "winflag": "1",
   "idmercado": "1"
   }],
   [{
     "value": "1.04",
     "datevalue": "2016-03-19 19:33:13",
     "winflag": "1",
     "idmercado": "2"
   }]]
```

Comment: I think it is valid JSON, but it's not clear where you're trying to get a dictionary..  You should consider using either DataContractSerializer or Json.NET too, I think you'll get better support there

Comment: You should look up [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (NewtonSoft JSON). It provides much cleaner Serialization/Deserialization, and even the MSDN article on JavaScriptSerializer recommends using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. [0[{ },{ }][1[{ },{ }]  
Maybe this is a better way to convert to a dictionary?

Comment: Your JSON is for an array of arrays... so deserialize it for that first, and then call to dictionary on the array using the index as the key

Comment: Thanks a lot Johnny, it resolved!!

Answer (score 0):

Like Johnny says, my json string is an array of arrays. So, I used a special paste for the build the structure of classes. 
This solution is on the this post:
[How to deserialize a JSON array with nested arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476663/how-to-deserialize-a-json-array-with-nested-arrays-of-objects)

```
public class Rootclass
{
    public List<Class1> rootClass { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string datevalue { get; set; }
    public string winflag { get; set; }
    public string idmercado { get; set; }
}

List<List<Class1>> myDeserializedObjList =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Class1>>>(json);
```